# Jump to specific slide by by clicking link on owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have implemented owl carousel in my website. The Carousel Slides are related to the navigation menus. That means when i will click one of the menus the carousel will show that specific slide. I tried it with `to.owl.carousel` but is not working for me. I tried like-

```
$('#award').click(function(){
    $('#home').trigger('to.owl.carousel', 2)
});
```

where `award` is the menu id and `home` crousel id. 2 is the position of the slide.

My website is http://tonitro.com/test/

How can i trigger this?

Comment: The reference states that the position (or other parameters) must be in []. I've tried and made it work using the to.owl.carousel. Hope it helps! Here is the reference: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `owl.goTo` event to slide your owl carousel to specific slide.

```
$('#home').trigger('owl.goTo', 2)
```

Your problem is that you don't have element with `id="award"` in your html, so `$('#award').click` will not work.

If you want to trigger the slide when you click on the Award on the top menu you should change your html there to:

```
<li><a href="#portfolio" id="award">Awards</a></li>
```

So `$('#award').click` will trigger click on that element

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working :)